# Manticore Search fail indexing with error ERROR: table 'idx: error opening...Too many open files

Tags: database, full-text-search, manticore-search, manticore

I hav a 70M rows table with 90 text fields,(45 fields with sql_field_string command ).
The first process worked perfectly with all 70M rows parsed by indexer, but after a little time, all the process fail with this error :

> ERROR: table 'idx: error opening ‘/var/lib/manticore/data/idx.tmp.spidx.0.tmp’: Too many open files.

My server is a cloud VPS with 1GB bandwith, 10 cores, 60G ram and 1.9T disk space.

I have re-tried by deleting all files in the folder…no way for the indexing operation to success.
Any clues / advices ?
Thanks guys !

Comment: The limit to number of files opened, is controled by the operating system. Will need to do some additional diganosis, to find if indexer is hitting a system wide limit, or a per process (frankly it unlikely to be per process, as indexer only opens a modest number of file per index at once, should always below 20) - so most likly system wide limit https://www.google.com/search?q=Too+many+open+files.